Does "a crew" mean 'a group of crew members' of "a crew member"?
From SpaceX to host first civilian spacewalk 1:07

Geoscience professor and astronaut Dr. Diane Proctor is the first and
only African American woman in space. As a mission pilot, I was the
mission pilot for Inspiration4, which was the first all-civilian
mission to orbit. She knows firsthand about those final hours of prep
for a crew ahead of a lift-off with historic significance.

When we say "crews", we always mean different groups of people, so when we use 'a crew', do we mean "a crew member" of "a group of members"?

When we use a crew, we generally mean members of a group working in such an environment, like in a ship or aircraft. It usually doesn't refer to a crew member.
